# Swift: Screen Freezing from time to time when Dismissing a ViewController displaying a picture over the current context

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionviewcell, photo

I am having some troubles with: The screen freezing from time to time when Dismissing the ViewController displaying a picture over the current context.

May someone provide me some insights on how to fix this problem?

A sample of my codes is found below:

import UIKit

class ViewControllerCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    addSubview(showPhotoButton)

    showPhotoButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 200).isActive = true
    showPhotoButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 160).isActive = true
    showPhotoButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    showPhotoButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


lazy var showPhotoButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Show", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showSale), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor(r: 120, g: 80, b: 255), for: .normal)
    return button
}()


@objc func showSale() {
    let popupViewController = PopupViewController()
    popupViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    popupViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
    window!.rootViewController?.present(PopupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

import UIKit

class SalePopupViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.60)
    view.isOpaque = false

    view.addSubview(rebateImage)
    view.addSubview(dismissButton)

    dismissButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    dismissButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    dismissButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    dismissButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    rebateImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    rebateImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -35).isActive = true
    rebateImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 290).isActive = true
    rebateImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true


}

let dismissButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissPopup), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

let rebateImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.layer.masksToBounds = false
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    image.image = UIImage(named: "SaleCostco")
    return image
}()

@objc func dismissPopup() {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Debugging tip: When the screen freezes, pause the app in Xcode's debugger and examine what's happening on your main thread.

Comment: Doing UI operations like dismiss in an asynchronously without making self weak poses many problems, I suggest always doing [weak self] of [unowned self] depending on the situation (in this case weak self would be adequate) and then referring to self.dismiss as self?.dismiss. By the way why do you need to dipatch to global queue then back to main queue? Doesn't seem to be necessary

Comment: Thank you for your help! Problem Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Your asynchronous code doesn't make sense. You dispatch onto a global queue and then immediately back onto the main thread. Try simply changing the implementation of dismissPopup() to this:

```
@objc func dismissPopup() {
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!